# Regex: how do you match Korean (hangul) letters in javascript (ES6)?

Tags: javascript, regex

How do you find Korean letters using regex in JavaScript?

Comment: Closing this as duplicate of a newer question which solves problems in the answer to this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following regex

```
const re = /[\u3131-\uD79D]/ugi
```

This is the code table that I referenced: http://memory.loc.gov/diglib/codetables/9.3.html

Try it yourself:

```
const re = /[\u3131-\uD79D]/ugi
console.log("abcde".match(re)) // null
console.log("안녕".match(re)) // ["안", "녕"]
```

Comment: What about `var hangul =/[\u1100-\u11FF\u3130-\u318F\uA960-\uA97F\uAC00-\uD7AF\uD7B0-\uD7FF]/g`? It does not even require the `/u` modifier. Also, here is a similar solution to yours without a regex: https://github.com/stonexx/hangul.js/blob/master/src/isHangul.js

Comment: One shouldn't rely on this regexp. For instance `'餃'.match(re) !== null` will returns `true` which doesn't comply with the problem "is the input ONLY a Korean string" ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52989330/what-is-proper-way-to-test-if-the-input-is-korean-or-chinese-using-javascript